# Event procedure working when subform is open directly but not when in parent form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form containing a subform with a query results. I associated a procedure to the on Click event in the subform.
If I open the subform directly the procedure is working properly when I click on a record. However when the subform is loaded by the main form nothing is triggered when I click on the record on the subform.
Is that normal ?

Comment: No it isn't. So debug your secret code.

Comment: @Gustav .There is not secret code. There is not really a code. Right now I just have a debug.print in the Click() procedure called by the [Event Procedure] from the On Click or the On Got Focus properties of the subform record. Like teh subform is not listening  to those events.

Answer (score 1):

in most cases, this means the button code has "hard coded" form name or whatever.

So, you might have this code in the form (which as you note will become a sub form).

```
' user clicked on a row or button , do somthing
 
dim lngPK as as long
lngPK = forms!frmInvoices!ID
```

or maybe this:

```
lngPK = [forms]![frmInvoices].[ID]
```

But, when you using a sub form, the form is NOT really open, but is a child of the sub form.

So, in most cases you can (and should) remove ANY hard coded form reference, and the above code will become

```
    lngPK = Me!ID
```

So, in most cases, to "mean" and "reference" the current form, (even as sub form), then do NOT hard code the forms reference expressions.

Use "me" when possible, since:

```
the code will work if you re-name the form
the code will work if you re-use, copy, past to other forms
the code will work if your code is "now" to run as sub form code.
```

We can't see your code that is breaking, but in 99% such cases where the code works in the form, but DOES NOT work when you use the same form as a sub-form?

Then it is the forms reference paths used.

Remember, when you use a form as a sub-form, then that form is not really "open" like a regular form anymore.

```
  in code, then this:

  somevar = [forms]![frmInvoice].[InvoiceNumber]

  becomes:

  somevar = [forms]![Name of Parent Form].[frmInvoice].[form]![invoiceNumber]
```

You can see in a real hurry how very messy this becomes.

So, for any reference of values or controls in that existing sub form, remove the hard-coded reference(s) that include the form name, and use "Me".

Comment: Thank your for the info. I actually have no code like you describe. I just have Click subform
`Private Sub Safety_Tag_number_Click()`
`Debug.Print "Test2"`
`End Sub`
and [Event Procedure] in the On click in the properties from the subform.

Comment: But it make sens that if the subform is not really open, it does not listen to the on click action in that subform. I'll have to think of something else.

Comment: Click events in that form (now nested as a sub form) should work just fine. I don't see why a simple button + click event in a sub form would stop working - it should work as normal, and as noted, about the only requirement here is to be aware of referencing controls etc. by using a hard coded forms! name, but other than that issue, what you have should work just fine. Consider opening the form as a non sub form, and test the click button. But, if that click works, then close, and open form with sub-form and try again. Might be due to no data. (button in details without data will not work).

Comment: The on click and on Focus are not for a button but for a field in a query result. And indeed, when I open the subform directly as a non subform the On click and On Get Focus subs are triggered and the debug. print is displayed. but As soon as that subform is in a parent form nothing happens.

Comment: Hum, if this is a datasheet, then I would consider changing over to a continues form (multiple items) form. But, it should still work. Datasheets don't like being inside of a form being launched as a acDialog form, so that might be the issue also. We might need a working example posted for further analyses.